# elementary os will not start after installing GPU drivers

Tags: startup, elementary-os, gpu

I was having some problems with my laptop (asked a related question yesterday: http://elementaryos.org/answers/after-locking-the-computer-screens-look-all-messed-up) regarding some dual-screen issues. This morning my laptop fan was working at full speed. Looking for some help I found a Q&A that made some sense (I thought): http://elementaryos.org/answers/luna-running-hot-on-my-laptop-1 , so I followed the instructions:

1. Did this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring
   ```
2. Then this:

   ```
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/121675171/fixplymouth
   chmod +x fixplymouth
   ./fixplymouth
   ```

After rebooting, my dual-screen (which used to work fine) stopped working, having this error message when I tried to change second monitor settings:

```
"required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(...), minimum=(...), maximum=(...)"
```

I tried installing AMD Catalyst drivers for my GPU (which apparently went fine, but at the end it said that something went wrong) and when I tried to reboot, I could not get to the desktop anymore: I just get a black screen with the keyboard cursor blinking on the top left corner of the screen.

Any ideas on how to solve this (if there is something I can do :( )?

Comment: Can you still switch to a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1? It would be nice to have X11's error log (`grep EE /var/log/Xorg*.log`).

Comment: I couldn't, but I tried again and now I can (I even got the OS logo on screen). On Ctrl+Alt+F7 I have a lot of [OK], the last one being: `Stopping Userspace bootsplash [OK]`; but it stays there (cursor blinking). Grepping that I have some error: `/Xorg.0.log: (EE) fglrx(0): atiddxDriScreenInit failed, GPS not been initialized.` `Xorg.0.log: (EE) fglrx(0): Failed to map FB memory` `Xorg.0.log: (EE) fglrx(0): firegl_SetSuspendResumeState FAILED -9.` `Xorg.1.log: (EE) Failed to load module fglrx (module does not exist, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got to fix one of my problems. I can see my desktop now the same way I had it before installing the ATI drivers. Did it by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

Found this solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602441&page=2&s=3da4d5fca1bc3b5ff037eab10b05702d). Apparently, having elementary os drivers and ATI drivers gave me some conflict so I had to uninstall one of them.

Thanks to @JohnWHSmith for leading me to the solution ;)

Comment: `fglrx` is the proprietary driver. You were probably trying to install the open-source one, and they don't do well together :)

Comment: Right! Actually, it was the other way around. I was trying to install the proprietary driver for fixing something and I ended up messing everything. Thanks ;)